# Finding the poles of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find the poles of:

$$f(z)=\sinh \frac{z}{z^2-1}$$

My answer is $\pm 1$. To check I was not missing anything I asked Wolfram (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pole+sinh%28z%2F%28z%5E2-1%29%29)) who tells me it cannot find any poles for this function. Have I misunderstood the definition of a pole or is Wolfram being quirky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the singularities of this function are essential singularities, not poles. There is no positive integer $n$ and function $g$ holomorphic at $\pm 1$ such that our function is equal to
$$\frac{g(z)}{(z-(\pm 1))^n}$$

Comment: Looks good to me - I wonder why someone downvoted?

Comment: @MarkMcClure I was wondering the same thing.